# google apps script I want to define a recurrence for all months first saturday

Tags: google-apps-script, recurrence

I have a problem with recurrence. I'm not able to define a recurrence for all months, only the first saturday

I have this code:

```
var bck_startdate = new Date("January 7, 2012 22:00"); 
var bck_enddate = new Date("January 7, 2012 23:00"); 
eventRecurrence.addMonthlyRule().onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.SATURDAY);
var cal_event=cal_netbackup.createEventSeries("TEST,bck_startdate,bck_enddate,eventRecurrence,{description:"TEST_DESCRPT"});
```

But the result is all weeks on saturday. If I enter on eventserie directly on calendar and I press weekday it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can ensure it's only the first Saturday of the month by limiting the days of the month to the first seven.

```
var recurrence = CalendarApp.newRecurrence().addMonthlyRule()
    .onlyOnWeekday(CalendarApp.Weekday.SATURDAY)
    .onlyOnMonthDays([1,2,3,4,5,6,7]);
```